# How to parse the multiple values using data bank or CSV file in OFT(Oracle functional testing)

Tags: automated-testing, java, functional

I am working on the OATS (Oracle Application test suite) tool for OFT.

Written code in Java by using the property file & added the data bank to the script. It takes only the first values both in the email/password field. But data bank has 5 values, all values have to parse in email/password field.

Now I want to parse the multiple values using the data bank property or with.CSV file within code written in functional testing. It works fine when I click on Iterate button.

Please help out how to write the code.

Below is the code written:

```
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.browser.api.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.functionalTest.api.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.utilities.api.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.utilities.api.sql.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.utilities.api.xml.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.utilities.api.file.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.webdom.api.*;



public class script extends IteratingVUserScript {
@ScriptService oracle.oats.scripting.modules.utilities.api.UtilitiesService utilities;
@ScriptService oracle.oats.scripting.modules.browser.api.BrowserService browser;
@ScriptService oracle.oats.scripting.modules.functionalTest.api.FunctionalTestService ft;
@ScriptService oracle.oats.scripting.modules.webdom.api.WebDomService web;

public void initialize() throws Exception {

    browser.launch();

}

/**
 * Add code to be executed each iteration for this virtual user.
 */
public void run() throws Exception {



    web.dialog("/web:dialog_unknown[@text='Content from the Web site listed below is being blocked by the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration.' and @index='0']").clickButton(0);
    web.window("{{obj.AvitekDB.window}}").navigate("{{obj.AvitekDB.URL}}");//Launch Browser & Placing the Avitek Url
    web.link("/web:window[@index='0' or @title='Avitek Medical Records Application - Microsoft Internet Explorer']/web:document[@index='0']/web:a[@text=' Start using MedRec! ' or @href='http://localhost:7011/medrec/index.action' or @index='2']").click();//Click on the Start Using Medrec Button
    web.link("/web:window[@index='1' or @title='Oracle WebLogic Server - Medical Record Sample Application - Microsoft Internet Explorer']/web:document[@index='0']/web:b[@text='Login' or @index='1']").click();//Click on the Patient Login


    getDatabank("AvitekDB").getNextDatabankRecord();
    web.textBox("{{obj.AvitekDB.EmailTxtBx}}").setText("{{db.AvitekDB.Email}}");//Username
    web.textBox("{{obj.AvitekDB.PasswordTxtBx}}").setText("{{db.AvitekDB.Password}}");//Password


    web.link("{{obj.AvitekDB.SubmitLnk}}").click();//Click Submit
    web.link("{{obj.AvitekDB.LogoutLnk}}").click();//Click Logout





}

public void finish() throws Exception {
}
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you clear out the question- are you not able to iterate or are you having an error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example would help you

```
getDatabank("demoCSV").getNextDatabankRecord();
    //get Record count
    int recordCount = getDatabank("demoCSV").getDatabankRecordCount();
    String count = Integer.toString(recordCount);
    info("Record Count = " + count );

    //get specific record 
    int recordCoun1 = getDatabank("demoCSV").getDatabankRecordCount();
    for (int i=1; i<=recordCount; i++) {

        System.out.println("Name :"+eval("{{db.demoCSV.empName}}"));
        getDatabank("demoCSV").getNextDatabankRecord();
    }
```

Where demoCSV is a csv file with column empName